# Why is my script not working in this html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and I'm teaching myself HTML and Javascript as well as python.
I got to a point in learning these languages were I felt like I could do one of the things I was working on in html using javascript.
I ran into a problem where for whatever reason my code simply isn't working. 
I double checked everything and I'm pretty sure it's all in the right place and all of the characters are correct.
Here is my code so far in it's entirety. I'm still pretty early in development and I understand that this isn't complete.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Python game</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Enter your choice by clicking on the buttons below the paragraph<p>

<p id="newText">kjgkhg</p>
<button type="onClick" id="ChooseFirst">First choice</button>
<button type="onclick" id="chooseSecond">Second choice</button>
<button type="onclick" id="choosethird">Third choice</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "why doesn't this work?";

funciton darkRoom() {
    vars x=document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML ;
    document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "You wake up in a dark room with no \
    idea how you go there. You can make out the outline of three doors\
    labeled '1', '2', and '3' directly in front of you. There is no door behind you.\
    Which door do you enter?";
}

function lions() {
}

function tiger() {
}

functoin bear() {
}

function brickRoad() {
}

function quickSand() {
}

function sizePuzzle() {
}

function riddlesOnWall() {
}

function wolfSheepCabbage() {
}

function duckHunt() {
}

function hangman() {
}

function goldRoom() {
}

function ocean {
}

function winScreen () {
}

function youDie() {
}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have a lot of simple typos in your code. Also, javascript is case sensitive

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console. The errors are printed there.

Comment: I though I was using camel case correctly here. What did I mess up in terms of case sensitivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot typos in it as Chris L already pointed out and as much as Juhana is right but the errors printed in the console are hard to decipher for a beginner (although you *have* to learn them, especially as a beginner!).

Here is some stripped down template you can play with

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Python game</title>
<script>
function darkRoom() {
    var x=document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML ;
    // You cannot escape the end-of-lines you have to concatenate individual strings
    document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = "You wake up in a dark room with no " + 
    "idea how you go there. You can make out the outline of three doors" +
    "labeled '1', '2', and '3' directly in front of you. There is no door behind you." +
    "Which door do you enter?";
}
// instead of alert() call another function reacting to the users input
function firstChoosen()  {alert("first choosen");}
function secondChoosen() {alert("second choosen");}
function thirdChoosen()  {alert("third choosen");}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="darkRoom()">
<p>Enter your choice by clicking on the buttons below the paragraph<p>
<p id="newText"> </p>
<!-- there are better methods but it's ok for now -->
<button onclick="firstChoosen()" id="ChooseFirst">First choice</button>
<button onclick="secondChoosen()" id="chooseSecond">Second choice</button>
<button onclick="thirdChoosen()" id="choosethird">Third choice</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Steve you can use what you want, it is a template and the `alert()` a placeholder for whatever your mind can come up with to inform the user about the result; from a nicely formated pop-up to ringing-a-bell, all is possible.

Comment: cool. I was going to try to include that in each individual function. Would it be considered better to include that in their own function? Is it worth putting the script for this in its own file.

Comment: You don't need a seperate function for every button, of coruse, you can do it all in one function and use an argument for the function to tell which button has been chosen as an answer to some question. Let's say something like `answerToQuestion(buttonNumber,QuestionNumber){...}`. You might use a long `switch()` to implement it, or use a database (e.g.: JSON if you want to stay in JavaScript) where you store all questions and answers in. It is easier to build it yourself than to port it from another language if you don't understand *both* languages well. And if you get stuck: ask.

Comment: I'll be doing that loads. This is harder than I expected. When is appropriate to use switch statements instead of if statements?

Comment: can you show me examples of your second comment. I just realized that I have no idea how to do any of that. Where would I learn how to do that? clearly w3schools is not enough

Comment: The book that seems to get recommended here is the one at http://eloquentjavascript.net/ It is free (CC-BY-NC) online but there is a paperback, too. Please buy the print version if you can spare the money to support the author.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you are learning programming and I'm happy to help you with your code. I noticed a few errors in your code that might be causing it to not work properly. Here are some suggestions to fix them:

- In HTML, the type attribute for buttons should be "button", not "onClick" or "onclick". The onclick attribute is used to specify a function to run when the button is clicked. For example, `<button type="button" id="ChooseFirst" onclick="darkRoom()">First choice</button>`
- In JavaScript, the word "function" is misspelled as "funciton" and "functoin" in some places. Make sure you spell it correctly and consistently.
- In JavaScript, the word "var" is misspelled as "vars" in the darkRoom function. Make sure you spell it correctly and consistently.
- In JavaScript, the word "ocean" is missing a pair of parentheses after it in the function declaration. Make sure you add them like this: `function ocean() {`
- In JavaScript, you have not defined any functions for the other buttons. You need to write some code for each button to change the text and the choices according to your game logic.

I hope these suggestions help you fix your code and make it work. Good luck with your game!